# how to open <href> in another tab on clicking the link first

Tags: hyperlink, href

Need to refresh currently opened tab on each click on an image with out opening the image url again and again  on new tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this

***Example***

```
    <a href="LINK" target="new"><img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="20px" height="35px"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this

```
<a href="LINK" target="_blank"><img src="IMAGE URL"></a>
```

example

```
<a href="file:///D:\images.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="file:///D:\images.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I tried this,but every time on clicking the image,a new tab is getting opened.I need a new tab when i clicked the link at first time.after that on clicking the link,same tab refreshing until its closed.